# How do I view application directories and directories that begin with dot in Netbeans on OSX?

Tags: macos, netbeans, view, directory

How do I view directories that begin with dot and how do I browse application directories in Netbeans?

I can't seem to view directories that begin with a "dot" through the open file dialog in Netbeans. Similarly, I can't browse any application directory e.g. File->Open File->"someapp.app". Attempting to browse "someapp.app" gives the error "someapp.app is a directory".

Altering or removing the regex under Preferences->Miscellaneous->File->Ignored Files Pattern has no effect; directories that begin with dot stay invisible.

I'm on OSX 10.5.8 and I've tried to get this working on netbeans 6.5-6.8 to no avail. I posted this to the on the netbeans irc and mailing list but haven't heard anything back.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If it's using the global finder prefs, you can show them system wide with

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

If you want to do it on a file by file basis (both show and hide), look into the SetFile utility script.